# Opencms change directory of site

Tags: opencms

I have opencms 10.5.4, tomcat 8.5.37.

I have a site "localhost:8080", now i have to move the site to "localhost:8080/mydirectory"

I tried to change opencms-system.xml

```
<sites>
            <workplace-server>http://localhost:8080/mydirectory</workplace-server>
            <default-uri>/sites/default/</default-uri>
            <shared-folder>/shared/</shared-folder>
            <site server="http://localhost:8080" uri="/sites/default/" title="Demo Site" position="3.4028235E38" webserver="true">
                <parameters>
                    <param name="locale.main">it</param>
                    <param name="locale.secondary">en</param>
                </parameters>
            </site>
        </sites>
```

I restarted catalina but nothing happens.

What is the best way to change domain url without breaking the links of the css and files that are in the modules?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want to achieve. If you just want to access your website through an additional folder to let's say distinguish from other sites you could just create a folder within the OpenCms workplace and move all your content to that folder.
Create the folder in the root directory of your site (e. g. `/sites/default/mydirectory/`).

Changes to `opencms-system.xml` are not necessary for this. So please remove `mydirectory`from your workplace-server configuration.

HTH

Best regards

Kai

Comment: i can't move content. I know that is a strange situation but I need "www.mysite.com/opencms/opencms/". i can do that, i can run the site but links generated by opencms (ex menu) have only one opencms es:   "www.mysite.com/opencms/". how can tell to opencms to write links and url for my needs?

Comment: Hi Mario, OK, understood. There is an OpenCms Rewrite filter configured in web.xml. I don't the exact Name. This filter makes the one opencms to go away. So you just have to deactivate that filter.

Comment: i found the solution editing opencms-importexport.xml